# Allah forgives if a sin is repeated even though I am aware of it and do not actually want to do it

Tags: allah, sin, forgiveness

what is the Islamic view of a sin if I ask forgiveness for it and make dua for it even though I am aware of it and still do it.  Will Allah be able to forgive us for this or is this contradictory from an Islamic view?  Deep down I don't want this, but I feel very unpressed by this and uncomfortable, partly because I live in a western country